# Un-select highlighted area on toggle click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have a Table with multiple cell.

It have below functionality:

- On hover it highlight the current cell with related area.
- On click it keep the highlighting on same position.

Here is **[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Lomva13g/)** for example.

I want if I click  on the black box again it will un-select/un-highlight this cell and other related area. Just like toggling. Currently no one can un-selsect once they selected any so I am trying add option to un-select by clicking again.

How it can be done ? Any help will be appreciated.

**JS**

```
var rows = $('#graph-table tr');
var graphSize = rows.length;
rows.each(function (index, el) {
    var singleCell = $(el).find('td');
    singleCell.each(function (i, cell) {
        $(cell).attr('data-row', graphSize - index - 1);
        $(cell).attr('data-col', i);
    });
});

$('#graph-table td').click(function (event) {
    $('#graph-table td').removeClass('g-clicked g-selected');
    $(this).addClass('g-clicked g-selected');
    $(this).prevAll('td').addClass('g-clicked');
    var colPos = $(this).data('col');
    var nextRows = $(this).closest('tr').nextAll('tr');
    nextRows.each(function (index, el) {
        var targetCol = $(el).find('td[data-col="' + colPos + '"]');
        targetCol.addClass('g-clicked');
        targetCol.prevAll('td').addClass('g-clicked');
    });
});

// make the graph
$('#graph-table td').hover(function (event) {
    $('#graph-table td').removeClass('g-hover g-selected-hover');
    $(this).addClass('g-hover g-selected-hover');
    $(this).prevAll('td').addClass('g-hover');
    var colPos = $(this).data('col');
    var nextRows = $(this).closest('tr').nextAll('tr');
    nextRows.each(function (index, el) {
        var targetCol = $(el).find('td[data-col="' + colPos + '"]');
        targetCol.addClass('g-hover');
        targetCol.prevAll('td').addClass('g-hover');
    });
}, function (event) {
    $(this).removeClass('g-hover');
});

$('#graph-table').mouseleave(function (event) {
    $(this).find('td').removeClass('g-hover g-selected-hover');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check if the clicked td already has the classes 'g-clicked g-selected' then just remove those classes but do nothing else [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lomva13g/7/)

```
$('#graph-table td').click(function (event) {
    if($(this).hasClass('g-clicked g-selected')){
        $('#graph-table td').removeClass('g-clicked g-selected');
    }
    else {
         $('#graph-table td').removeClass('g-clicked g-selected');
        $(this).addClass('g-clicked g-selected');
        $(this).prevAll('td').addClass('g-clicked');
        var colPos = $(this).data('col');
        var nextRows = $(this).closest('tr').nextAll('tr');
        nextRows.each(function (index, el) {
            var targetCol = $(el).find('td[data-col="' + colPos + '"]');
            targetCol.addClass('g-clicked');
            targetCol.prevAll('td').addClass('g-clicked');
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh ! Thanks I couldn't realize that.

Answer (score 1):

In the `$('#graph-table td').click()` function, you could check first to see if the user has clicked on the same square they clicked previously. A simple way to do that is like this

```
$('#graph-table td').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass("g-selected"))) {
        //Remove selection
    } else {
        //Add selection
    } 
}
```